# Eliminate this error message 'Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.'

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

I really need help. I spent a lot of time but I can't solve this problem..

When I add a new post and then redirect to the post list page,
this error message appears "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.".

Also empty item added on the list page. but when I refresh the page, the empty item is gone.

Please check the code and give me advice for this problem.

When I enter the list page, fetchPosts() loads empty array.
[image]

After I add new post then redirect to the list page, the error appears.
Also the empty item is added on the list.

[image]

QnA.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPosts } from '../actions';
import './QnA.scss';


class QnA extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPosts();
    console.log(this.props.qnas);
  }

  renderList() {
    return this.props.qnas.map(qna => {
      return (
        <div className="item" key={qna._id}>
          <div className="content">
            <div className="postTitle">
              <Link to={`/qna/${qna._id}`}>
                <span><b>{qna.title}</b></span>
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div className="postInfo">
              <span>{qna.author}</span>
              <span>{qna.createdAt}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr />
        </div>
      );
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="QnA">
        <h1>QnA</h1>
        <div className="list">
          {this.renderList()}
        </div>
        <Link to="/qnanew">
          <button className="ui brown button">New Post</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { 
    qnas: Object.values(state.qnas)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts })(QnA);
```

action - index.js

```js
//Create a Post
export const createPost = (formProps) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const author = getState().auth.nickName;
  const response = await baseURL.post('/qnanew', { ...formProps, author });
  dispatch({ type: CREATE_QNA, payload: response.data });
};

// List
export const fetchPosts = () => async dispatch => {
  const response = await baseURL.get('/qna');
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_QNAS, payload: response.data });
};
```

qnaReducer.js

```js
import _ from 'lodash';
import { FETCH_QNA, FETCH_QNAS, CREATE_QNA, EDIT_QNA, DELETE_QNA } from '../actions/types';

const qnaReducer = function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    // One Item
    case FETCH_QNA:
      return { ...state, [action.payload._id]: action.payload };
      // List
    case FETCH_QNAS:
      return { ...state, ..._.mapKeys(action.payload, '_id') };
    case CREATE_QNA:
      return { ...state, [action.payload._id]: action.payload };
    case EDIT_QNA:
      return { ...state, [action.payload._id]: action.payload };
    case DELETE_QNA:
      return _.omit(state, action.payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default qnaReducer;
```

[image: Actual post list page. There is an empty item]

[image: console.log shows empty array when the page render first time.]

Comment: please show `props.qnas` value. And show your code instead a picture

Comment: if qna._id is not unique you could take the index from the map function for example.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code - there is probably an issue with the `qnas` that you've defined. I would guess a missing or duplicate ID in there.

Comment: I don't see an issue with how the array is rendered, I suspect the issue is in your data being mapped. Can you share how `state.qnas` array is defined and how it's updated? If updating the `state.qnas` array is a reproduction step for the issue then please also include the data it is being updated with.

Comment: Finally I solved the problem. The actual problem was at the backend side. There was wrong response and it caused the empty item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React you have to use 'key' in each child on the list. example :

```
const data_users = [{name: "james", age: "19"},{name: "brandon", age: "20"}

renderList(){
   return data_users.map((data, index) => {
      return <div key={index}>{data.name}</div>
   }           // ^ you need this key, simply put the index value just in case if you dont have unique identifier
}
```

The problem in your code problably because your qna.__id doesnt have uniqe value.

Hope this help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I finally solved the problem. Before I change the key index, the items' order were randomly loaded. But now it is ordered. thanks!!